# Ubuntu Virtual Server - mount read only for file recovery

Tags: server, mount, virtualization, data-recovery, ext4

I will recover a file with extundelete. The system is Ubuntu on a Linux Virtual Server.

First, I want to mount drive as read only:

```
mount -o remount,ro -t ext4 /dev/ploop34760p1 /
```

Get:

```
mount: / is busy
```

The file recovery fails because of the problem above:

```
extundelete --output-dir '/root/abc' --restore-file '/path/to/file/abc.txt' /dev/ploop34760p1
extundelete: failed to read-only open device "/dev/ploop34760p1": Error code 1
```

I have stop/kill all processes so far. Checked with:

```
lsof / | awk '$4 ~ /[0-9].*w/'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you boot in recovery-mode? There are all filesystems mount ro, from the start.

Comment: Pick a different mount point. `/` is a bad idea - the system you are using is mounted there (that's why it's busy). Instead, try /media or /mnt

Comment: tried /mnt: mount: /mnt/ not mounted or bad option

Comment: can anybody help?